# How to show turn by turn navigation in android

Tags: android, google-maps, navigation, maps

I have source and destination points(latitude and longitude), but I am not able to show turn by turn navigation. then how to show turn by turn navigation from source to destination.
Please help me.
Thanks in advance...:)

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro

Use the directions API to return a list of directions in JSON, you can then plot these directions using Polylines.

Additionally it returns the HTML instructions which gives you the wording for directions.

Answer (score 0):

While you won't be able to do this with Google Maps, you could do this with an OpenStreetMap based solution:

- [Scout SDK](http://developer.skobbler.com/)
- [OSMBonusPack](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack)

Comment: is it still the case? Can we use Google maps API for tun by turn navigation?